# Convert array of unsigned char (byte) into unsigned short in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, unsigned, unsigned-char

I have `array^ byteArray` and I need to extract bytes in Little Endian sequence to make unsigned shorts and ints. I've tried every combination of the following I can think of so am asking for help.

```
int x = UInt32(byteArray[i]) + (UInt32)(0x00ff) * UInt32(byteArray[i + 1]);
int x = UInt32(byteArray[i]) + UInt32(0x00ff) * UInt32(byteArray[i + 1]);
int x = byteArray[i] + 0x00ff * byteArray[i + 1];
```

The problem is the least significant byte (at i+1) I know it is 0x50 but the generated short/int reports the lower byte as 0x0b. The higher byte is unaffected.

I figure this is a sign error but I can't seem to be able to fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using managed code.  Endian-ness is an implementation detail that the framework is aware of:

```
array<Byte>^ arr = gcnew array<Byte> { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
int value = BitConverter::ToInt16(arr, 1);
System::Diagnostics::Debug::Assert(value == 0x302);
```

Whether the framework's assumptions are correct depends on where the data came from.

Comment: On the MSDN help page I find ToInt16 sample indicating the array 01-02-03-04 yields ToInt16(arr, 1) == 0x20. Unless I missed something. Thanks for the speedy expertise offered.

Answer (score 2):

The proper way to generate an 16 bit int from two 8 bit ints is `value = static_cast< int16_t >( hibyte ) << 8 | lobyte;`

Comment: You should also cast `hibyte` to the 16-bit data type, otherwise, if it is an 8-bit data type, the left shift will turn it into a 0.

Answer (score 1):

```
int y = byteArray[i] | byteArray[i + 1] << 8;
```

is what you need to use. (see also [Convert a vector<unsigned char> to vector<unsigned short>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1898212/convert-a-vectorunsigned-char-to-vectorunsigned-short))

Answer (score 0):

You want to do this instead

```
int x = UInt32(byteArray[i]) | (UInt32(byteArray[i + 1]) << 8);
```

Your multipliers are messing things up.

Comment: You're trying to do a shift.  The multiplication can emulate a shift but you're multiplying by 255 which won't emulate a shift.

Answer (score 0):

You have to multiply the second byte with `0x0100` instead of `0x00ff`.

It's like in the decimal system, where you multiply by ten, not by nine.

Comment: Even so that doesn't account for making the byte 0x50 into 0x0b.